# Elixir Explorer Equivalent to pandas fillna

Tags: elixir, elixir-explorer, elixir-nx

I'm translating a pandas script to Elixir using Explorer.DataFrame.

I found [`Explorer.Series.fill_missing/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/explorer/Explorer.Series.html#fill_missing/2), which will handle a single column.

Is there a recommended way to mirror pandas' `fillna` such that the entire DataFrame's `nil` values will be replaced with whatever I provide?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with [`Explorer.Query`](https://hexdocs.pm/explorer/Explorer.Query.html#content) in a more efficient way:

```
require Explorer.DataFrame, as: DF
alias Explorer.Series

DF.mutate(iris,
  for col <- across() do
    Series.fill_missing(col, 0.0)
  end
)
```

Answer (score 0):

After much trial and error, I found this to work.

```
alias Explorer.DataFrame, as: DF
alias Explorer.Series

fillna = fn val ->
  fn n, df ->
    DF.mutate_with(df, &%{n => Series.fill_missing(&1[n], val)})
  end
end

df
|> DF.names()
|> Enum.reduce(df, fillna.(0.0))
```